# TYPO3 News extension, image upload size

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.1.x

Im running TYPO3 v. 6.4 Fluid/Extbase.

Im working with the News (news) Extension and it's working fine, but i have a little problem.
When i make a new news and go to Relation and add an image (800x600) then it's resize it to 100x80.

What file do I look after, so i can changes the resize, so I get the size 800x600. 
Have scanned the folder for the extension and can't find any place that handle the image udload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## SETUP

```
plugin.tx_news {
  settings {
# only for DETAILS VIEW
    detail {
      media {
        image {
          maxWidth =
          maxHeight =
        }
      }
    }
# only for LIST VIEW
    list {
      media {
        image {
          maxWidth =
          maxHeight =
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

greetings
maty